# How to recognize options only in the begging of arguments in argparse?

Tags: python, argparse

I'm writing a python program that mainly calls another program, like the `watch` program. In `watch -n1 date -u`, only `-n1` is an option for `watch` (`-u` is an option for `date` and a positional argument for `watch`). `getopt.getopt` provides such parsing in python. argparse is easier to use, but it parses like `getopt.gnu_getopt`. How to enable `getopt.getopt`-like parsing in argparse? Otherwise, is there an alternative commonly installed package for argument parsing I could use instead?

Comment: Take a look at the [intermixed-parsing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#intermixed-parsing)

Answer (score 0):

In argparse, add a positional argument with `nargs='...'` instead of `nargs='*'`. Then, this positional argument will consume all arguments after the first one, even if some of them look like options.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-n', dest='interval')
parser.add_argument('command', nargs='...')
args = parser.parse_args('-n1 date -u'.split())
# args = Namespace(interval='1', command=['date', '-u'])
```

In optparse, use [`disable_interspersed_args`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/optparse.html#optparse.OptionParser.disable_interspersed_args).

Comment: `'...'` as value for `nargs` doesn't appear to be documented anywhere…?

Comment: I know the `nargs='...'` syntax from https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/58174#issuecomment-1093569642.

Comment: Mmm, funky that…